# java.lang.NullPointerException in Page object Model

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, testng, chromedriver, page-factory

I have created this program using TestNG and i'm getting this error java.lan*g.NullPointerException
I have initialized the Webelement .But still i'm getting error

POM.java

```java
package TestPOM;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
public class POM {
    public WebDriver driver;
    @FindBy(how=How.XPATH,using ="//a[@href='/tasks/tasklist.do']")
    public WebElement lnk_MyAccount;
    
    @BeforeClass
    public void openBrowser() {
          System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","E:\\Users\\codeRefactor\\CodeRefactor\\Jar\\chromedriver_win32\\Chromedriver.exe");
          driver=new ChromeDriver();
          driver.manage().window().maximize();
          driver.get(" url");
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void Login()
      {
          driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("admin");
          driver.findElement(By.name("pwd")).sendKeys("manager");
          driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
      }
    @Test
      public void createcustomr(){
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, POM.class);
        lnk_MyAccount.click();
        
         }
      
      @AfterMethod
      public void Logout() throws InterruptedException
      {
          Thread.sleep(20000);
          driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Logout']")).click();
      }
      
    @AfterClass
      public void closeBrowser()
      {
          driver.close();
      }
    
}
```

can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

When you construct the page using `PageFactory.initElements(driver, POM.class);` the new instance of the page is created so that the field that you are referring is still `null`.

What you are doing though is pretty tricky. I would rework your design actually. However changing the mentioned line to `PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);` might help you..

**P.S.** - The latter injects the fields into existing object rather than creates a new one of the specified type.

Comment: Thank you so much @Alexey R for you clear explanation! It's working fine

Comment: Great! Feel free to mark my answer as correct.